# Need EqualIgnoreCase when getting index

Tags: java, android

```
String s ="Ganesh";

System.out.println(""+s.indexOf("ga"));
System.out.println(""+s.indexOf("Ga"));
```

When I run this, I get `-1` for `s.indexOf("ga")` and `0` for `s.indexOf("Ga")`

I want to get `0` for both.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the string you're looking for to lower or upper case when using `indexOf`, this way you'll always get the correct index regardless of casing

```
String s = "Ganesh";
String s2 = "ga";
String s3 = "Ga";

System.out.println(s.toLowerCase().indexOf(s2.toLowerCase()));
System.out.println(s.toLowerCase().indexOf(s3.toLowerCase()));

> 0
> 0
```

You can even put it into your own method like this:

```
public int indexOfIgnoreCase(String s, String find) {
    return s.toLowerCase().indexOf(find.toLowerCase());
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
String s = "Ganesh";

System.out.println(indexOfIgnoreCase(s, "ga"));
System.out.println(indexOfIgnoreCase(s, "Ga"));

> 0
> 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no `indexOfIgnoreCase()` method, but you can achieve the same with using `toLowerCase()`.

```
System.out.println(""+s.toLowerCase().indexOf("ga"));
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `indexOf` case-insensitive you can convert the Strings to lowercase first:

```
System.out.println("" + s.toLowerCase().indexOf("ga".toLowerCase()));
System.out.println("" + s.toLowerCase().indexOf("Ga".toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: I think it's toLowerCase.. Can't edit due to some restrictions

Answer (score 1):

use the `toLowerCase()` or the `toUpperCase()` method of the `String` class, before you use the `indexOf()`.